# Jqgrid with Datepicker

Tags: php, jquery, jqgrid, datepicker

I want to use the datepicker in my jqgrid. I have already tried few things which i have searched on this site, but they did not work. Please help.

I have jqgrid, which is getting data from PHP. Fields includes email & search_date. When the grid loads, it shows the data from the database. I want to show the current data & the also calendar icon next to the search_date so that the user can also modify this field as well. After modification, it should be saved to the database.

I have removed whatever things i have tried. So this is fresh code :

```
function fileview(SITEURL){

    jQuery("#gridList").jqGrid({ 
        url:'/mycrm/process/viewjson',
        datatype: "json", 
        colNames:['Email','Search Date'], 
        colModel:[
                  {name:'email',index:'email', width:50, align:"center"},
                  {name:'search_date',index:'search_date', width:17, align:"center"},
                 ],
        rowNum:25, autowidth: true, 
        rowList:[25,50,100,200], 
        mtype: "POST",
        pager: jQuery('#pager1'), 
        sortname: 'id', 
        viewrecords: true, 
        sortorder: "DESC",
        multiselect: true,
        caption:"Details",
        height:'',width:'' }).navGrid('#pager1',{search:false,refresh:false,edit:false,add:false,del:false});
    ReloadGrid('/mycrm/process/viewjson');
}
```

Currently it is showing the search_date & want to add calendar icon to select the new date & then modify it to the database.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't use any **editing** of the grid. You have to include `editable: true` property in a columns of `colModel` which you want to allow the user to edit and then use one from the [editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jqgriddocs#editing). You can call `datepicker` inside of `dataInit` callback function of [editoptions](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:common_rules#editoptions). You can just search for `datepicker` and `dataInit` words on the stackoverflow (see the results [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bjqgrid%5D%20%2Bdatepicker%20%2BdataInit)) and you will find many code examples which you can use. I would you recommend to confider to use `formatter: "date"` additionally. It can convert input data for `search_date` returned from the server in some more readable format. Typically one uses some language independent format in communication with the server, for example ISO 8601 (string like `2014-12-31`).